# -min-crossrefs in .bib

Tags: bibtex

Is there any way to control the minimum threshold for crossrefs in a bibliography other than using command line arguments?

The [FAQ](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf) says that it is not possible to control this in the .bst in version 0.99c. Is there a way (in version 0.99d) to control this either in the .bib or .tex?

Cross referencing is handy so I'd rather not copy the relevant fields into each of the entries.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about BibTeX 0.99d, but there's biblatex 1.3a. `:-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  mincrossrefs=99,% Default: 2
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{A01,
  crossref = {Z99},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@incollection{B02,
  crossref = {Z99},
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@collection{Z99,
  editor = {Zuthor, Z.},
  year = {1999},
  title = {Zulu},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's handy, but to use `biblatex`, I think I first need to get [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/a-biblatex-style-thats-like-plainnat) answered.