# A biblatex style that's like plainnat

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I want to switch to `biblatex` but despite the rather minimal changes suggested in some [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) to switching from `natbib`, there's really a lot that seems to need changing. For example, the "In:" needs to [go](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex). The order of entries [needs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles) to [change](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6743/biblatex-changing-the-order-of-entries). The book edition field needs to change as well as move. Basically, there's a lot more to do than suggested in the answers to the first question.

Is there a simple way that I can start with a `biblatex` style that behaves exactly like `plainnat` (modulo the incompatible changes to the various fields like edition) and then tweak it from there?

It's not worth my time right now (deadlines, you understand) to start from `numeric-comp` and then try to figure out what needs to change in order to match `plainnat`. This is exacerbated by needing to have two slightly different versions of the `.bib` (again, for things like edition) to test for differences.

Comment: Does anyone actually use `plainnat`? Like every 'standard' style I've ever seen, it's a nice model but not _useful_, as you should always be matching some published style, which inevitably is not the same as any of the 'standards'.

Comment: @Joseph: I've published mostly with ACM, IEEE, and USENIX. IEEE provides a BibTeX style file. The others do not. (It may depend on the particular conferences, so others may have different experiences.) For ACM and USENIX, the plain style is used. So I find it pretty useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid the short answer is: Simple, `biblatex`, exactly like `plainnat` -- choose two out of three.

Longer answer: As soon as you provide exact specifications in what way, say, the `numeric-comp` style needs to be modified in order to pass as an exact `plainnat` replica, it should be possible to provide these modifications. (There's also the possibility that a custom style is a better starting point.) However, if you have to meet a deadline right now, I would advise to postpone the switch to `biblatex`.

Comment: If I knew what needed to be changed, then I could probably do it. But part of the problem is that I don't know for sure. I listed things that I found with two references. Since I don't know for sure how many things need to be changed, I'm hesitant to make the switch. And there's always another deadline.

Answer (score 2):

This solution gives you a format very similar to plainnat.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
```

Comment: The option `firstinits=true` would seem to run counter to the `plainnat` approach. At least I've never known it to abbreviate first and middle names.

Comment: I'd prefer `\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\space}` over `\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }`.

Comment: `style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,citestyle=authoryear` is equivalent to `style=authoryear, firstinits=true`, which is shorter and less confusing.