# Make \cite{my reference} show name and year

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to figure out how to make author's name and year show up every time I make a reference.

For example:

`my_bibtex.bib` has this entry:

```
@article{Franklin1999,

author = {Franklin Allen and Risto Karjalainen},
title = {Using genetic algorithms to find technical trading rules},
year = {1999},
volume = {51},
pages = {245-271},
journal = {Journal of Financial Economics}

}
```

If in `my_paper.tex` I use this line:

```
Important result has been found by \cite{Franklin1999}
```

My output looks like:

```
Important result has been found by [1]
```

But I want it too look like:

```
Important result has been found by Franklin 1999
```

I there a way to do it?

My `bibliographystyle` is set to `plain`

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{my_bibtex}
```

Comment: The `plain` bibliography style isn't easily adapted to authoryear-style citations. Better to use the `plainnat` bibliography style, the `natbib` package (load it with option `authoryear`), and commands such as `\citet` and `\citep` ("textual" and "parenthetical" citations -- macros provided by the `natbib` package).

Comment: Probably »[biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)« would be a suitable option here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `natbib` citation management package and the `plainnat` bibliography style. (Note that the `plain` bibliography style is not well-suited for authoryear-style citations.) As always, run `latex`, `bibtex`, and `latex` twice more to generate the bibliography and compile the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}   % omit 'round' option if you prefer square brackets
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\citet{Franklin1999}
\bibliography{my_bibtex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, for some reason when I run your code. I get this error: `! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year`, I asked another question about it, about the same time you posted this answer: citations.http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135668/what-is-the-proper-bibliography-format-to-use-with-natbib

Comment: @Akavall - When switching from one bibliography style to another, e.g., from `plain` to `plainnat`, it's prudent to wipe out all auxiliary files (including the `.aux` and `.bbl` files) prior to rerunning latex/bibtex/latex/latex. Please check if deleting the previous batch of auxiliary files does the trick.

Comment: Note that plainnat works even if you do not load package natbib: natbib is a way to improve even more the result.

Comment: @Arnaud - I'm afraid I have to disagree with your claim. `natbib` is not just a way to "improve" the look of the citation call-out. Indeed, I'd say that loading `natbib` is *essential* to making the output of `\cite` presentable. To wit, if `natbib` isn't loaded, `\cite{Franklin1999}` produces `[Allen and Karjalainen(1999)]`; I strongly doubt that most readers would find this acceptable.

Comment: @Mico That's strange, I tried yesterday and could not see any difference, maybe I made a mistake during compilation.

Answer (score 36):

The simplest way is to use the bibliography style: **apalike**, instead of plain. Here is:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{References}
```

---

A more powerful package is `natbib`. In your case, use `citet` for textual citations.

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\citet     #textual citations, print the abbreviated author list
\citet*    #textual citations, print the full author list

\citep     #parenthetical citations, print the abbreviated author list
\citep*    #parenthetical citations, print the full author list

\citealt    #the same as \citet but without any parentheses.
\citealp    #the same as \citep but without any parentheses. 


\citeauthor{ale91}         #Alex et al.
\citeauthor*{ale91}        #Alex, Mathew, and Ravi

\citeyear{ale91}           #1991 
\citeyearpar{ale91}        #(1991)
```

Comment: A little bit late to ask this question, but I'll do so anyway: Why is using the `apalike` bibliography style the "simplest way"? E.g., in what sense might using the `apalike` style be simpler than using the `plainnat` style?

Comment: My tex does not print the abbreviated author list with \citep, it instead prints the full list. why?

Comment: +1 to what Mico asked

Comment: This helped me, thanks

Comment: For completeness, there are also `\citetitle`, `\citedate`, and `\citeurl`.

Comment: @Arnaud - SparkandShine's suggested solution -- to use the `apalike` bib style instead of `plainnat` -- is incomplete in the sense that it, too, requires loading a suitable citation management package. One such package could be `apalike` (yes, the package name and the bib style name are the same), and another one is -- you guessed it, `natbib`. That is why I had raised the question, a bit more than seven years ago, if using `apalike` instead of `plain` or `plainnat` really was the "simplest way".

Comment: @Mico I got confused because in the accepted answer there is usepackage{natbib}. The way it is redacted strongly suggests painnat cannot be used without natbib. I just tested: it can.

Comment: @Arnaud - I guess it comes down to one's choice of the meaning of the phrase "cannot be used". If the objective is merely to compile the document without throwing an outright syntax error, then \cite will indeed "work" -- and thus "can be used" -- even if `natbib` isn't loaded. However, if the typesetting objective is a tad more ambitious, such as wanting to generate a decent-looking authoryear-style citation call-out, then I don't see a way around loading `natbib` when using `plainnat`. That said, I really don't understand your apparent aversion to loading `natbib`.

Comment: @Mico I have absolutely no aversion to loading natbib ;-) Just trying to figure out things.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is something like the `authoryear` citation style of the `biblatex` package.
If you are trying to follow a particular citation style, it would be best to say which in your original question; a `biblatex` style likely exists for it.

To compile this example, run

```
pdflatex my_paper
biber my_paper
pdflatex my_paper
pdflatex my_paper
```

#### `my_paper.tex:`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{my_bibtex.bib}
@article{Franklin1999,
        author = {Allen Franklin and Karjalainen Risto},
         title = {Using genetic algorithms to find technical trading rules},
          year = 1999,
        volume = 51,
         pages = {245--271},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Financial Economics}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{my_bibtex.bib}

\begin{document}
Important result found by~\cite{Franklin1999}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Is there a ready-made biblatex style that emulates the "classic" `plain` (or `plainnat`) bibliography style?

Comment: @Mico I believe just leaving the style as the default (`numeric`) does this, but I would take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/a-biblatex-style-thats-like-plainnat as well (in case I don't understand what you're asking)

Comment: Thanks. I've checked out the answers you've linked to. It would appear that the option `FirstInits=true`, stated in the second answer, may not be a correct implementation of the `plainnat` style. By the way, the default look of `biblatex`'s authoryear setup doesn't look all that close to that of `plainnat` either. (For the record, I actually prefer the look produced by `biblatex`!)

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why did you transpose the first and last names of the first author? The person's name really is "Franklin Allen", *not* "Allen Franklin". The `author` field provided by the OP was correct...

Comment: @Mico looks like just a silly mistake :-)

Answer (score 2):

I did not want to switch to natbib, so I made a workaround,
using info from:
https://ctan.joethei.xyz/info/biblatex-cheatsheet/biblatex-cheatsheet.pdf

```
\citeauthor*{example_1}
\citeyear{example_1}
```

or

`Author, year \nocite{example_1}`

will do the trick while using bibtex with biber.

Comment: Can't you just load a different style: `style=authoryear,` and use `\autocite` as normal? Usually it should not be necessary to go for constructions like `\citeauthor*{example_1 \citeyear{example_1}` and solutions like this can have issues (try citing two works by the same author from the same year).

Comment: You could, but then it would change the behaviour throughout the document. I wanted to show ho it could be done as an exception, when you want to mention for example just the author/year when discussing their results. In those cases: "Where [1] showed that ..." just does not look as good as "Where Mr. Author, 2000, showed that ..."

Comment: In that case I'd use `Where \textcite{sigfridsson} showed that ...`. `\textcite` is defined in all `biblatex` standard styles and most contributed standard styles and is generally meant to be used for exactly these narrative citations.

Answer (score 1):

`plainnat` is a better option I think

I use,

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\Mycite[1]{(\citeauthor{#1}~(\citeyear{#1}))}
.
.
.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{referencesfile}
.
.
.
```

and the result looks

> Peng and Chen (2015)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The plainnat style is also recommended by the accepted answer, so could you please highlight which improvement your answer makes?