# What is the proper bibliography format to use with natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have recently asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/make-citemy-reference-show-name-and-year) and comments there helped, but I still can't get the result that I am looking for. I reduced my problem to a simple case:

Here is my test_bib.bib:

```
@article{Franklin1999,

author = {Franklin Allen and Risto Karjalainen},
title = {Using genetic algorithms to find technical trading rules},
year = {1999},
volume = {51},
pages = {245-271},
journal = {Journal of Financial Economics}

}
```

When I try to run this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin {document}

\title{My Title}
\author{MyName}

My test \citet{Franklin1999}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test_bib}

\end {document}
```

I get this error:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

What am I doing wrong? I think that format of my `.bib` file is wrong, but I don't see where.

When I run the code with commented out parts for `cite` and use `\cite` instead of `\citet` everything works fine.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the test files. The only  problem could be that you still have the old auxiliary files (compiled with `plain` and `cite`). Remove the auxiliary files `.aux` and `.log` and `.bbl` and compile again `latex bibtex latex latex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whither `natbib` is  being able to  interpret the bibliography style correctly. Check that all the entries e.g, years placed correctly.

After changing the argument to `\bibliographystyle` a run of LaTeX and one of BibTeX are necessary to get back in sync. Removing the .bbl and .aux files before those run is necessary.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do.