# natbib - authoryear citations displayed as brackets [1]

Tags: natbib, harvard-style

I'm trying to use harvard style referencing, and thouhgt I had it figured out, but the citation is shown with brackets.  Here is my sample doc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,norsk,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}   
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}
I følge Andersen m.fl.\citep{Erdos65} har...
\bibliography{myref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

and my myref.bib document in the same folder:

```
@article{Erdos65,
title = {Some very hard sums},
journal={Difficult Maths Today},
author={Paul Er and Arend Heyting and Luitzen Egbertus Brouwer},
year={1930},
pages={30}
}
```

The output is "I følge Andersen m.fl.[1] har..."

So it seems that the reference to the .bib file is ok.  I added the authoryead option to natbib - but is did not change anything.  I have tried to delete all generated files.

Comment: The problem seems to be the same as in [Natbib In-Text Citation displays (author?)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/); you should use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`

Comment: For another earlier posting on the same subject, see [Make \cite{my reference} show name and year](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135649/5001).

Comment: Thank you both - you are right egreg - it is the same problem, but I did not read that post, as I regarded the subject to to be the same issue.

I'm prepairing for my master theisis.  Last time I wrote a master thesis (in 2001), I wrote in Word.  I'm glad I have time to prepair - because I am really struggeling with getting a grip on LaTeX (and associated software).  But I'm getting there - and if I return with other basic/beginner questions, I hope you guys have patience with me :-)

Comment: @BjornBjornstad - You should by no means feel bad about posting a question that turns out to be a potential duplicate of earlier postings. (It can be quite difficult at times to discover and evaluate prior relevant postings.) Glad you're using LaTeX for your project -- I believe you'll find the look of the finished product to be far better than what can be achieved by some of the alternatives.