# Using 2 citation call-out formats within the same article

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

**Format of references with BibTex**

With Bibtex one can add references to other articles in the text that by adding numbers in square brackets (e.g `[2]`).

As explained in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135649/make-citemy-reference-show-name-and-year), it is also possible to format the reference in the standard `author (year)` with `natbib` citation management package and the `plainnat` bibliography style.

**Example of having two different formats in one article**

However, there is often a need for two different reference formats in the same article. A format that is used when the authors are subject or objects of a sentence and a format when the references are added in parentheses. Consider for example an extrait from [Charlesworth et al. 1997](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=3317&fileId=S0016672397002954):

> [..] frequency of the common allele (Nordborg et al., 1996b). As discussed by Nordborg et al. (1996b), the exact model of [..]

Here there are two formats for the (same) reference

- `author (year)`
- `author, year`

**Question**

Is it possible to have a system that allow to specify at each `\cite{}` what format we want to use (without messing up with the bibliography at the end)?

I suggest to use the above two formats (`author (year)` and `author, year`) as example.

Comment: This is a standard pattern, and `natbib` provides two citation commands for it: `\citet` which yields `Name (xxxx)` and `\citep` which yields (Name, xxxx). `biblatex` has similar facilities with its `\textcite` and `\parencite`.

Comment: See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793) for a detailed explanation with respect to the APA style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both citation call-out formats are examples of author-year style. The first,

> (Nordborg et al., 1996b)

is called "parenthetic" citation call-out style. With `natbib`, it's produced with

```
\citep{<key>}
```

The second call-out style, viz.,

> Nordborg et al. (1996b),

is known as a "textual" style; with `natbib` it's generated via

```
\citet{<key>}
```

The [natbib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) package provides additional citation-related macros; do familiarize yourself with the package's [user guide](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).

Comment: Great! Thanks for this nice explanation +1. I think you meant `\citet{<key>}` for the textual style.

Comment: @Remi.b - Thanks for pointing out this typo: Indeed, it should have been `\citet`; fixed the typo in the meantime.