# I can't find .bst file

Tags: bibtex

I want to make my bibliography to show full first name and last name but last name first, so I followed instructions here: [How to make last names of authors appear first in my bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375413/how-to-make-last-names-of-authors-appear-first-in-my-bibliography)

The problem is I can't find the .bst file. I went into a texlive directory, but the bst folder was empty. The directory I found was `Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨usr⁩ ▸ ⁨local⁩ ▸ ⁨texlive⁩ ▸ ⁨texmf-local⁩ ▸ ⁨bibtex⁩ ▸ ⁨bst`

Is there something wrong with my tex settings? Do I need to reinstall?

Comment: texmf-local is just for any local additions you have made, with standard settings files in the distribution  will be under texmf-dist, but if you are looking for `wibble.bst` use `kpsewhich wibble.bst` in the terminal and it will echo the full path if it is installed at all,.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

`texmf-local` is just for any local additions you have made, with standard settings files in the distribution will be under texmf-dist, but if you are looking for `wibble.bst` use

```
  kpsewhich wibble.bst
```

in the terminal and it will echo the full path if it is installed at all